# Proper way to add unescaped text from a field to a regex in postgres?

Tags: regex, postgresql

What's the proper way to add a literal text value from a field to a regex in postgres?

For example, something like this where some_field could contain invalid regex syntax if left unescaped:

```
where some_text ~* ('\m' || some_field || '\M');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use a regex to prep your string to be in a regex. Escaping non-word characters in your string should be sufficient to make it regex-safe, for example:

```
=> select regexp_replace('. word * and µ{', E'([^\\w\\s])', E'\\\\\\1', 'g');
   regexp_replace   
--------------------
 \. word \* and µ\{
```

So something like this should work in general:

```
where some_text ~* x || regexp_replace(some_field, E'([^\\w\\s])', E'\\\\\\1', 'g') || y
```

where `x` and `y` are the other parts of the regex.

If you didn't need a regex at the end (i.e. no `y` above), then you could use [`(?q)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX):

> An ARE can begin with *embedded options*: a sequence `(?xyz)` (where `xyz` is one or more alphabetic characters) specifies options affecting the rest of the RE.

and a `q` means that the:

> rest of RE is a literal ("quoted") string, all ordinary characters

So you could use:

```
where some_text ~* x || '(?q)' || some_field
```

in this limited case.

Comment: @mu is there any other way that would work without escaping all non-word characters? 
I have a similar problem but my strings contain a lot of non-word characters that I fear will have strange behaviors if escaped.

Comment: @JoãoAlmeida: PostgreSQL uses pretty strict [POSIX regexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) so I think escaping `[^\w]` is pretty safe, you're not going to produce anything regex-ish accidentally and you don't have to worry about `(` vs `\(` as with some regexes. The `(?q)` approach might be more suitable for you though.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks. The `(?q)` approach would be perfect for me if I didn't need to insert a regex after my string.