# How to treat part of a regex as a literal string on postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql, escaping

I have a piece of code like this:

```
Foo.where("name ~* '.*#{string}.*'")
```

Where *string* has both word characters and non-word characters and if some of them are not escaped I get invalid Regular Expressions errors.

So I need to get **postgreslq** to take *string* as a literal **or** escape the meta-characters used by the regex. Is there a way to do it instead of getting a list of all meta-characters and adding the backslash?

---

I have looked at both these questions but none of the answers is exactly what I'm looking for:

- [Proper way to add unescaped text from a field to a regex in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111304/proper-way-to-add-unescaped-text-from-a-field-to-a-regex-in-postgres)

**Here** the accepted answer escapes all non-word characters. And using that with my strings I am afraid there will be weird behaviors with escaped non-word characters.

- [What is the equivalent of regexp \Q...\E in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313964/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regexp-q-e-in-postgresql/21387206#21387206)

**Here** the answer is specific to the question and can't be used in my case.

Comment: See the following answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use Ruby's [`Regexp.escape()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) to espace characters in `string` that have a special meaning in a regular expression.

For example

```
> string = 'C++ /?|foo bar baz'
=> "C++ /?|"
> Regexp.escape(string)
=> "C\\+\\+\\ /\\?\\|foo\\ bar\\ baz"
```

With this in mind you would write

```
Foo.where("name ~* '.*#{Regexp.escape(string)}.*'")
```

<sub>**Note**: this is untested.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could just plainly convert all characters of `string` to the ASCII or Unicode hex number and use the \xhh or \x{hhhh}. Should easy to code and should not have side-effects.